# Get statistics from MySQL json rows

Tags: mysql, sql, json

In my table I have column which stores json representation of survey. It has the next format:

```
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     survey 
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|[{"answers": ["1"], "question": "..."}, {"answers": ["1"], "question": "..."}, ...]
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|[{"answers": ["2"], "question": "..."}, {"answers": ["1"], "question": "..."}, ...]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Question holds text of question, answers holds array of strings(answers) user gave on question. Order of questions is the same in each record.

How can I get answers statistics on each question. I mean, how many users choose `1` option on 1st question and etc.

**UPD**:
Got solution that works if question have 1 answer, in my case this is appropriate solution. Thanks to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for userful(no) reference:

```
SELECT
   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('count', count, 'answer', answer)) as data,
   question 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         count(*) as count,
         answer,
         question 
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(survey, CONCAT('$[', idx, '].answers[0]'))) as answer,
               JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(survey, CONCAT('$[', idx, '].question'))) as question 
            FROM
               user_profiles 
               JOIN
                  (
                     SELECT
                        0 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        1 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        2 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        3 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        4 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        5 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        6 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        7 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        8 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        9 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        10 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        11 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        12 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        13 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        14 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        15 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        16 AS idx 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                        17 
                  )
                  AS indexes 
            WHERE
               JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(survey, CONCAT('$[', idx, '].question'))) IS NOT NULL 
         )
         as qa 
      GROUP BY
         answer,
         question 
      ORDER BY
         question 
   )
   as anwers 
GROUP BY
   question;
``
```

Comment: Can you share more details? Why don't you use a better database structure that enables reading this data simply?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a limitation, I have to to work with existing tables structure.

Comment: What kind of details do u exactly need to understand the problem?

Comment: @Barmar my page didn't get refreshed. Was about to delete it. Sorry for it.

Comment: You have to write a procedure that iterates over the array. It can't be done in SQL.

Comment: You could use CASE statements to match an exact string,
e.g. 
CASE
    WHEN survey CONTAINS ('{"answers": ["1"], "question": "..."') THEN 1